# Filter by name of element in object

Tags: angularjs, object

I want to filter an object like so:

```
<td ng-repeat="(key,value) in contact | contactEditableFields">
<editable-string-field in-edit="contact.editing" original-string="contact[key]" editable-string="contact['editing'+key]">
</td>
```

With my custom filter looking like:

```
.filter('contactEditableFields', function (){                                                                     |~                                                                                                                     
  return function(contact){                                                                                       |~                                                                                                                     
    var contactEditFields = {};                                                                                   |~                                                                                                                     
    angular.forEach(contact, function (v,i){                                                                      |~                                                                                                                     
      if (i.search('editing') <0 && i!='pk' && i!='$$hashKey'){                                                   |~                                                                                                                     
        contactEditFields[i]=v; 
      }
    });
    return contactEditFields;                                                                                                                  
  };
})
```

And my contactobject looking something along these lines (attributes in no particular order), and yes both of these types of contacts will happen:

```
c = { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", pk: 1337, editing=false }
```

or:

```
c = { firstName: "John", editingfirstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe", editinglastName:"Doe", pk: 1337, editing=true }
```

Now this works as I have intended it to - with my intentions being to make it very easy to add new attributes to my "contact" object. However I now have a desire to order the fields being outputted as well in the custom filter (ie do contact['lastName'] before contact['firstName'] before contact['email']), and I understand it's bad practice to rely on my object being ordered when I `ng-repeat` it.

The ways I've come up to fix it that which I don't like/haven't a clue as to how to do:

-Change contact to an array (probably the worst option, my database is nicely giving me JSON contacts and I don't want to have to mess with that again!)

-Somehow do editing in a better way than just copying the main strings into new attributes and deleting these extra attributes when I'm done

-Hardcode each parameter (am I trying too hard to make this elegant and nice, when it really can't be?)

-Do some filtering magic??

I'm quite new into AngularJS so if any of you experts out there have any experience with this kind of stuff and could point me into which direction I should pursue as well as some help with that direction it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So, you're looking to pass another parameter to your filter with hardcoded field ordering?

Comment: Well I'd do something like pass a configurable object on which to order it around - so that way my table isn't set in stone, and I can move stuff a column over easily.

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at is if you're passing in an ordering argument with a hardcoded list of fields, why do you need the logic in the filter which filters out object properties you don't want to display?

Comment: Well my hope would be that I'd pass in an array which is dynamically updated as the app is run - ie it could start as ["firstName", "secondName"], then go to ["lastName", "email", "firstName"] as the user moves stuff around

Answer (score 0):

Consider a solution where you:

- Convert your object properties into an array using a filter just before passing it to ng-repeat (ie. don't change original data structure). This is necessary in order to...
- Create an additional filter which accepts an array of key names as an argument and returns a filtered and ordered array to ng-repeat

The array of key names could be dynamic and change during run time by the user.

I made a [Plunker containing a sample app](http://plnkr.co/edit/IlNMFdgUcMjH1wtbIqmF?p=preview) following those guidelines.

The demo doesn't include your initial object map filtering since the desired key names are passed in inside of an array. But if you still need to use such a filter, say perhaps for defaults before the user reorders, you could add it back in.